# Patch Change with MainStage does not sync UltraBeat Patterns

Tags: logic-pro

I'm trying to use Apples Mainstage for Live-Performances. And because I have no drummer I am using UltraBeat as a Drum-Sequencer (or drum machine).

Following Situation:
In MainStage I created a "concert" which consists out of "songs". IN this songs I have "Patches" who are changing by a MIDI-command … like "Intro" -> "Verse" -> "Chorus" -> and so on …

At the Intro I have a Drum-Pattern in UltraBeat … and in "Verse" or "Chorus" there are different patterns (also in UltraBeat) ...

WHAT I WANT is that when I change the MainStage-Patch from "Intro" to "Verse", that the drum-pattern of the "Verse" isn't starting from beginning or .. IT SHOULD BE SYNCHRONISED .. so that there is a clean transition between the 2 patches.

THX in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I use Mainstage and had similar issues.

The way I eventually overcame it was by making each section a "song", rather than a "patch".

When I switch from one "song" to another (which I do with a MIDI foot switch) the Ultrabeat patterns remain synchronised, even if there is also a tempo change.